# Using List<Web Element> slows down the script badly

Tags: java, eclipse, webdriver, testng

I'm using the below code for asserting error message when Login is failed. Using this code, I'm successfully able to achieve the results, but it makes my script too slow.

```
List<WebElement> errorDivs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='errorMsg']"));
if (!errorDivs.isEmpty()) {
   System.out.println("Username Or Password is Incorrect" + username);
   // pick first one and use as main failure reason
   Assert.fail(errorDivs.get(0).getText());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In WebDriver, findElement, findElements will wait implicitly if specified element not found until it reaches TIMEOUT limit. That is why your script is waiting if that error divs are not present. Instead of using directly findElements , you can use your own logic to check whether the element is present or not.

Here logic goes

```
boolean isElementPresent(WebDriver driver,By by)  
 {  
               driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
               try  
               {  
                    driver.findElement(by);  
                   return true;  
               }  
               catch(Exception e)  
               {  
                   return false;  
               }  
              finally  
              {  
                  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
              }  
    }
```

Refer http://goo.gl/lw0gDa

Answer (score 1):

I get frustrated at people (not necessarily yourself) who say that xpath is bad to use without understanding why. Xpath is a great choice of selector when the more expressive CSS selector doesn't achieve what you want.

Comment: Sorry, i thought i added this as a comment